# Angular + Webpack: empty angular object on initialization

Tags: angularjs, webpack

Trying to use webpack + angular 1.5.5 + ng-forward. Webpack parses angular and builds it module by module. And during the angular initialization I'm getting the error at following function:

```
(function extendJQLite(proto) {
    ...
})(angular.element.prototype);
```

The error appears because the `angular` object is empty (`{}`). Why does it happens? How can it be fixed (except moving angular to the `externals`)?

My Webpack config:

```
{
    debug: true,
    cache: true,

    verbose: true,
    displayErrorDetails: true,
    context: './src',
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        reasons: true
    },
    entry: "./index.ts",
    output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: "build.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            __metadata: 'typescript-metadata',
            __decorate: 'typescript-decorate',
            __awaiter: 'typescript-awaiter',
            __param: 'typescript-param',
            angular: 'angular'
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it in two ways:

1) Using `imports-loader` in the main loaders section after `babel-loader`:

```js
loaders: [
    { test: /\.ts/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'import?angular!babel-loader!ts-loader' }
]
```

It works, but there are some other troubles forced me to stop using this way. So there is another way:

2) I just created a file `vendor.js` where all dependencies are required. As I understood it is a right way to work with webpack libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem and found a solution. The problem here is that angular 1 is not working nicely with webpack without a shim (see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2049). Try this webpack loader config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        /*
         * Necessary to be able to use angular 1 with webpack as explained in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2049
         */
        {
            test: require.resolve('angular'),
            loader: 'exports?window.angular'
        },
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'angular': 'angular',
    }),
],
```